# Add Back Button in Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a navbar that appears in my top of my app. I would like the navbar to look something like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                        |
| <-  Status                                             |
|                                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

In a failed attempt to do that, I've create the following navbar, which can be seen in this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/HJYOSztaPM).

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-default">
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </button>
      <div>
        <a class="btn btn-link btn-xs" href="/home"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left" style="font-size: 2.5rem;"></i></a>
        <div class="navbar-brand">Hello</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>           
</nav>
```

If you visit the Bootply, you can see that the arrow appears to the right of the title instead of the left. I have no idea what that is happening. Plus, the back button isn't vertically centered like the text. Why is the back button appearing after the title instead of before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you two ways about this:

One with `padding` and `float`, another with `flex`.

[**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/23Knh8HEVE](http://www.bootply.com/23Knh8HEVE)

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-default">
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-target="#menu" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </button>
      <div>
        <a class="mybtn btn btn-link btn-xs" href="/home"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left" style="font-size:2.5rem;"></i></a>
        <div class="navbar-brand">Hello</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>           
</nav>

<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class=" navbar-header navbar-default">
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-target="#menu" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </button>
      <div class="mycontainer">
        <a class="mybtn2 btn btn-link btn-xs" href="/home"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left" style="font-size:2.5rem;"></i></a>
        <div class="navbar-brand">Hello</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>           
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.mybtn{float:left;padding:15px;display:inline-block;}

.mycontainer{display:flex;align-items:center;}
```

**PS**:
*Your button is at right, because the brand is floating at left...*